# Read/write patter using java and ms sql server

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, concurrency, read-write

I have been experiencing a concurrency issue when using SQL server and java.
I have setup a message queue and have a system in place to read from this queue. For each message this is what happens:

1. Messageses contain a "quantity attribute". This attribute is read and it updates a row in table1 with such number.
2. Another table, table2 contains a "total" atribute and a row is read to get total value. table1 and table2 rows can be mapped using an Id.
3. table2 row is updated by adding quantity attribute from message.

The issue here is that when I have multiple instances of my service and both instances get a message to process same row, they write different values to table2. It is a sort of read/write pattern.

Example:

I got this on table2:

```
+------+-------+
| id   | total |
+------+-------+
| 1    | 100   |
+------+-------+
| 2    | 100   |
+------+-------+
```

and got two message to insert two rows on table1:

```
+------+-------+
| id   | qty   |
+------+-------+
| 1    | 10    |
+------+-------+

+------+-------+
| id   | qty   |
+------+-------+
| 1    | 50    |
+------+-------+
```

a) Message 1 arrives and tries to update total from table2, it reads 100 and updates total to 110
b) Message 2 arrives and tries to update total, since first message has not been completed, it reads total as 100 as well and it updates it as 150.
c) We expect total to be 160 (100+10+50), but we got 150, so state is incorrect.

Is there anything I can use to solve this concurrency issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, is necessary to add a lock in row. I suggest to implement a Double-Checked lock using DB locks - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking).

1 - Start the transaction (eg @Transactional annotation on your service method)

2 - Retrieve entity from database with the PESSIMISTIC_WRITE lock mode (make sure to indicate hibernate that fresh copy should be read instead of the one stored in session cache)

3 - Perform the change/update on the field

4 - Save the entity (and make sure to flush the value to the DB if you do not want to wait for the auto-flush)

5 - Commit the transaction (done automatically when using @Transactional)

While your transaction holds a lock on the target entity/db row, preventing other transactions from reading it while your update is in progress.

The implementation is look like this:

```
    @Transactional
    public void updateValue(int id) {
        final Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        final Table1 table = session.get(Table1.class, id,LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
        session.refresh(table);
        table.setCount(table.getNoteCount()+1);
        session.saveOrUpdate(table);
        session.flush();
    }
```

Hope this helps .